# Get a JAR File version number

Tags: java, jar, version, manifest

I have an application used in clustering to keep it available if one or more failed and I want to implement a way to check the version of the jar file in java.

I have this piece of code to do that (e.g.: in the class MyClass) :

```
        URLClassLoader cl = (URLClassLoader) (new MyClass ())
            .getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL url = cl.findResource("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
        Manifest manifest = new Manifest(url.openStream());
        attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
        String version = attributes.getValue("Implementation-Version");
```

When i run the jar as an application it works fine BUT when i use the jar file as a librairie in an other application, i get the version number of the other application.

So my question is, how can i get the manifest of the jar where MyClass is contained ?

NB : I'm not interested in solution using static constraint like 
'classLoader.getRessource("MyJar.jar")' or File("MyJar.jar")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i get the solution from a friend :

```
    // Get jarfile url
    String jarUrl = JarVersion.class
        .getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
        .getLocation().getFile();

    JarFile jar = new JarFile(new File(jarUrl));
    Manifest manifest = jar.getManifest();
    Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();

    String version = attributes.getValue(IMPLEMENTATION_VERSION)
```

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to obtain the Implementation Version is with the [Package.getImplementationVersion() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getImplementationVersion--):

```
String version = MyClass.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can code like :

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("/packages/file.jar"); //give path and file name
java.util.jar.JarFile jar = new java.util.jar.JarFile(file);
java.util.jar.Manifest manifest = jar.getManifest();

String versionNumber = "";
java.util.jar.Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
if (attributes!=null){
    java.util.Iterator it = attributes.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        java.util.jar.Attributes.Name key = (java.util.jar.Attributes.Name) it.next();
        String keyword = key.toString();
        if (keyword.equals("Implementation-Version") || keyword.equals("Bundle-Version")){
            versionNumber = (String) attributes.get(key);
            break;
        }
    }
}
jar.close();

System.out.println("Version: " + versionNumber); //"here it will print the version"
```

See [this](http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Jar/How_to_Get_the_Version_Number_of_a_JAR_File) tutorial, thank you. I also learn new thing from here.

Comment: Yeah i found this solution too but it don't solve my problem as i have to know the qualified name of my jar file. I want a dynamic solution that will work without constraint like file name :/ ..

Comment: Ok i have a solution ! Thanks to you!! Just let the time to post it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you know a class in the jar, you can get the location of the jar from the ProtectionDomain's CodeSource.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getProtectionDomain%28%29

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource%28%29

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/CodeSource.html#getLocation%28%29